# connection.query runs a maximum of 150 times and still varies in foreach

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Let's say that there are 1200 users on the list, he executes the query only 150 times and keeps varying the amount.

```
list.forEach( (value, index, array) => {

var rank;
if(value.rank == 1){
rank = 'normal';
}else if(value.rank == 2){
rank = 'administrator'){
}

connection.query("UPDATE users SET rank = ? WHERE id = ?", [rank, value.id], (err, res, fields) => {

});

});
```

Comment: Why do you not have a WHERE clause on the query? Every time, you are setting every row in the database to the same, new value

Comment: The code is just an example of what I want to do, I forgot to put it.

Comment: Does your connection library have a limit of concurrent connections? Since the query itself is async, you are effectively kicking off all of them 'at once'. Alternately, are you exiting your program after your forEach, but before every query has finished?

Comment: Yes, there are limits for simultaneous connections, but the normal was even if there was an amount in a row to be executed.